# there is no VSC partition in Intellij main menu

Tags: github, intellij-idea

[image]

nevertheless there IS github plugin enabled, project directory binded etc.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

but without VCS menu i can not create new repo at github

How can I add VCS to menu toolbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just found how to restore main menu options

[image]